# Load cdn file and save it in Service Worker

Tags: cdn, service-worker

Is it possible to load website with CDN bootstrap javascript and css file and save these files into Service Worker for offline ? I would like to find out how to download file from web online and store it for offline using. I really appreciate each advice or article.

Answer (score 6):

Service worker cache API does support caching for all CDN resources and you can use [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache)  provides a storage mechanism for Request / Response object pairs that are cached as part of the [ServiceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker) life cycle.

Infact [sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache) and [sw-toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox) are the most popular Service worker caching libraries that provides common caching patterns and an expressive approach for `Runtime Caching` and `Precaching` for static resources.

More techniques outlined in the [offline-cookbook](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/) to provide a robust offline experience with sensible fallbacks.